# Create a windows startup application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I wrote a application in VS 2010.  How do I make a installer that'll install my application as a windows startup application?  I need it to run each time windows starts.

Comment: Do you need it to run each time *Windows starts*, or each time *a user logs on*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the installer add a shortcut to the application in the startup folder.